# Sony Smartwatch Version 1 SDK manual install

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Can anyone tell me where I can get the manual install files for the Sony SmartWatch version 1 SDK?  When I try off the official site it only gives me version 2.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Using the Android SDK manager seems to result in missing files - can't get the extensions to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK v2 is backwards compatible so we have deprecated v1.  You should be able to use v2 to develop SmartWatch 1 extensions.

If you are getting compilation errors with the sample extensions make sure you have added the SmartExtensionUtils and SmartExtensionAPIs projects to your workspace and that they are properly referenced from your extension project (see the docs for step by step).